# How to call a objective-C method from javascript in phonegap ios version

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova

I am having a method in .m file and from javascript I want to send a string in return I will get a encrypted string.. how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom plugin for phonegap to call any method from a .m file of your project
 There is plenty of [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS) on this.
you can have a look at some [Tutorials](http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/) as well.

Finally if its only encryption you need and your encryption uses any of the standard algorithims ,you can find the same Algorithm implementation for javascript eg [jsaes](http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/) and [sjcl](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/)